# onEdit: How to reference cell from another sheet and write a cell value offset from that cell?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to use another sheet as reference to trigger an onEdit script. There is a cell in Sheet2 that changes to "Y" but is based on a reference equation. So I am trying to use Sheet 1 as the basis for onEdit. My question is, am I specifying the reference cell from the non active sheet, and then writing a status "Y" on an offset cell?

```
if( s.getName() !== "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  var col = r.getColumn();
  var col2 = col.offset(0,-5);
  var target = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(s.getSheetByName('Sheet2')).setActiveRange(col2,10);
  var stat = target.offset(-6,0);
  var status = stat.getValue();
  var time = new Date();
  time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");


switch(status) {
  case (status !== "Y"):
      target.setValue(time);
    break;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your code has a few inherent problems right off the bat.

`var col2 = col.offset(0,-5);` should not work, because of `var col = r.getColumn();` You are trying to use the `.offset()` method that has to be used on a range, however based on your code, `col` is an `integer`.

If you want to offset the active cell that is selected, then you would do `r.offset(0, -5)`. For example, we are on *Sheet2* and have Row 20, Column 10 active. Let's go over your code and see what you would get:

```
r = Range J20 on _Sheet2_ (specifically that sheet)
col = 20
```

Immediately we see that col2 will throw an exception. Going onwards, currently I see no reason to set the active sheet to another one. You can have range1 and range2 that you aquire by `sheet1.getRange(20,10)` and `shee2.getRange(20,10)`. Doing `range1.setValue("A")` and `range2.setValue("B")` will write A and B in J20 on different sheets.

Using the same scenario, of us being on J10 (once everything is fixed) `target.setValue(time);` will set the value in J10 (because you took the column number and set it as the row number). `stat` will be J4, because you offset the row by -6 on *Sheet2* range `target`

Comment: I was meant to say, I have made col 2 now as

Comment: That I could do it as var col2 = col-4? That would return as an integer. The only issue I have now is specifying the cell which I want to populate with a value from the other sheet. How do I reference a cell from the other sheet? Currently I am thinking  var target = SpreadsheetApp.Sheet('Sheet2').Range(col2,10); but I think that is wrong is it not?

Comment: In order to target a cell in another sheet, you must have an object. When working with multiple sheets you have several options. If you know that the sheets are always in the same order, you can have `var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getSheets()` and then target `sheets[0]`, `sheets[1]` etc. or if you know that the name is constant you can store both sheets in separate variables and just use `sheet1.getRange()` and `sheet2.getRange()` to get different ranges from different sheets. Also, if you are using `onEdit()` you can use an event object to get the edited range instead of `getActiveCell()`